# Required keys when destructuring

Tags: clojure

Is there a way to have an exception raised if the keys you're trying to destructure aren't in the map passed to your function? Would this be a good use case for a macro?

For example:

`(defn x [{:keys [a b]}] (println a b))`

I'd like this to work:

`(x {:a 1 :b 2})`

But this to raise an exception (:b is missing)

`(x {:a 1})`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about a [pre-condition](http://blog.fogus.me/2009/12/21/clojures-pre-and-post/)?

```
(defn x [{:keys [a b]}]
  {:pre [(some? a) (some? b)]}
  (println a b))

user=> (x {:a 1})
AssertionError Assert failed: (some? b)  user/x (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
```

Edit: Yes, you could use a macro to handle this for you. Maybe something like this:

```
(defmacro defnkeys [name bindings & body]
  `(defn ~name [{:keys ~bindings}]
     {:pre ~(vec (map #(list 'some? %) bindings))}
     ~@body))

(defnkeys foo [a b]
  (println a b))

(foo {:a 1 :b 2})
(foo {:a 1}) ;; AssertionError Assert failed: (some? b)
(foo {:a 1 :b nil}) ;; AssertionError Assert failed: (some? b)
```

Comment: pre-conditions seem perfect. If I want to do this without repeating the keys twice (definition and pre) would I have to use a macro? (I can provide more context if it's useful)

Comment: Awesome! FYI I had to switch from clojure 1.5 to 1.6 for your macro to work.

Comment: @spike `some?` was added in 1.6 - you could remove it entirely but the failing assertion would look like: `AssertionError Assert failed: b` - not as informative, IMO

Comment: How it could be handled with new clojure.spec mechanism?